# How to use a custom haddock executable to generate documentation with stack?

Tags: haskell, haskell-stack, haddock

I'm working on a new theme for Haddock and want to try it on some real projects. How can I configure stack to use my haddock executable? I don't see any config option in stack.yaml. I've also tried putting the new haddock executable into my PATH but that didn't help.

Comment: Try replacing `stack exec -- which haddock`.

Comment: While that works, it's only good as a workaround. I'd rather avoid having to overwrite files which are managed by stack.

Comment: Alternatively you can use `--system-ghc` to use _both_ the `ghc` and `haddock` that are on your `PATH`. This requires that the `ghc` on your `PATH` has the right version for your project.

Comment: I wonder if I can somehow extract the path to the stack-managed GHC (~/.stack/.../ghc-8.0.1/bin/), prepend the path to my haddock binary (so my haddock binary gets precedence), and then use --system-ghc. That would give me the best of both world: always an accurate version of GHC (managed by stack) while still allowing to use a custom haddock.

Comment: That's `stack path --compiler-bin`.

Comment: Unfortunately that doesn't work.

Comment: How does it fail?

Comment: The documentation is rendered with the old binary (and thus has the old style).

Comment: `stack path --compiler-bin` works for me with both v1.3.2 and HEAD.

Comment: Ah, sorry, I misunderstood you. You'll have to hide/rename the original haddock binary then. That works for me at least. Or you could submit a patch for a `--which-haddock` option, that would solve it for all of us! :)